# Storyboard: unified navigation bar with tabbed view hierarchy

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have this view hierarchy:

```
UINavigationColtroller
-> UITableViewController
   -> (push) UITabBarController
      -> (tab) UITableViewController [list view]
         -> (push) UIViewController [detail view]
      -> (tab) UITableViewController
         -> (push) UIViewController
      -> (tab) UITableViewController
         -> (push) UIViewController
```

The problem is that navigation bar customisations won't work for bottom 3 view controllers. It kind of makes sense, because there is a **stack** of navigation items 3 tab views are on the same level.

So I'm left with this alternative:

```
UINavigationColtroller
-> UITableViewController (1)
   -> (modal) UITabBarController
      -> (tab) UINavigationColtroller (2)
         -> (root) UITableViewController
            -> (push) UIViewController
      -> (tab) UINavigationColtroller (3)
         -> (root) UITableViewController
            -> (push) UIViewController
      -> (tab) UINavigationColtroller (4)
         -> (root) UITableViewController
            -> (push) UIViewController
```

This is terrible, because there are now four separate navigation stacks. Not only storyboard gets hideous, I also have add extra boilerplate in `#2`, `#3`, `#4` wiring the left button to go back to `#1` manually?

Is there a way to maintain the navigation with just **one** top-level navigation stack even if there is a tab bar in-between?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you ahead with

```
UITabBarController (Replace with UINavigationColtroller)
-> UINavigationColtroller (RW UITableViewController)
   -> (With hidden Tabbar) UITableViewController  (RW UITabBarController)
        ->  (push and show Tabbar) UITableViewController [list view]
        ->  (push and show Tabbar) UIViewController [detail view]
        ->  (push and show Tabbar) UITableViewController
        ->  (push and show Tabbar) UIViewController
        ->  (push and show Tabbar) UITableViewController
        ->  (push and show Tabbar) UIViewController
```